# Hide Vertical Scrollbars in ReactTable

Tags: reactjs, react-table

How do I hide vertical scrollbars in [`react-table`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table)?

I tried using `overflow-y: hidden`, but that always targets the window.

```
.ReactTable .rt-body {
  -ms-overflow-style: none !important;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: `I tried using overflow-y: hidden` show us in the code how you tried that

Comment: @Vencovsky  ``` .ReactTable .rt-body {
  -ms-overflow-style: none !important;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}```